# Does MS speech support custom vocabulary

Tags: microsoft-speech-api

I have a requirement to write an application which would take an audio file and identity precisely at which points in the file specific words are being spoken. These are not English words, but rather Aramaic words, so would have to be added as additional vocabulary. Does MS speech recognition support this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There are several options, depending on the specificities of your specific words.

- One is simply using `phrase list`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/improve-accuracy-phrase-list?tabs=terminal&pivots=programming-language-csharp
- One is called `Custom Speech`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/custom-speech-overview

The 1st one is easier to test and implement, as you will not need audio data for the training.